# Put text in Div sticky to bottom of window

Tags: css

I have an h4 nested in 2 divs like so

```
  <div id="my-team-lineup" style="text-align:center">
            <div id="myteamDiv" style="width:100%; ">
                <div id="myTeamBeforeDiv" style="width:50%; float: left;">
                    <center>
                        <h4>Before Trade</h4>
                        <div class="tableRow header blue" id="statTable0">
                            <div class="cell">Pos</div>
                            <div class="cell">Players</div>
                            <div class="cell">Opp</div>
                            <div class="cell">Proj Pts</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tableRow">
                            <div class="cell">
                                Text
                            </div>
                            <div class="cell">
                                Text
                            </div>
                            <div class="cell">
                            Text
                           </div>
                            <div class="cell">
                            Text</div>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <h4>Week At Bottom</h4>
                    </center>
                </div>
 </div>
```

I want to have this h4 sticky to the bottom of the page. I have tried every combination of position and bottom I can think of and nothing is working. Just a note as I have an exact replica of this that takes up the other 50% of the page, and the height of the divs can be different due to content.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/v6wybLb2/ check it out and it is fixed at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

First, you didn't closed all divs in your code. correct it.

You can set position as fixed and bottom as 0.
HTML

```
<h4>text</h4>
```

CSS

```
h4{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xxfhqv36/